# MongoDB C# 2.1 ReplaceOneAsync not working for repository pattern

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to implement async repository pattern for mongodb. This is my code:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class MongoDbRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    private IMongoDatabase _database;
    private IMongoCollection<T> _collection;

    public MongoDbRepository()
    {
        GetDatabase();
        GetCollection();
    }

    private void GetDatabase()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/");
        _database = client.GetDatabase("LocalTest");
    }

    private void GetCollection()
    {
        _collection = _database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }

    public async Task<ReplaceOneResult> Save(T doc)
    {
        return await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(w => w.Id == doc.Id, doc, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
    }
}
```

And console application which just calling the logic:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userRepo = new MongoDbRepository<User>();

        userRepo.Save(new User
        {
            FirstName = "fn",
            LastName = "ln"
        }).Wait();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In this line of code:

```
return await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(w => w.Id == doc.Id, doc, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

I'm getting an error:

> Convert([document]).Id is not supported.

If I'm changing the code like this, it's working:

```
private IMongoCollection<EntityBase> _collection;
    private void GetCollection()
    {
        _collection = _database.GetCollection<EntityBase>(typeof(EntityBase).Name);
    }
```

But I really need to use T instead of BaseMongoClass...
Any ideas why this error occurs and how can I fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just solved the same problem. Get rid of the `==`, for some reason the new mongo driver doesn't like it. I used `.Equals()`

Change

```
return await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(w => w.Id == doc.Id, 
    doc, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

To

```
return await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(w => w.Id.Equals(doc.Id), 
    doc, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

Answer (score 3):

If your using an Interface one would also find this problem,

Solution Instead of id use _id

```
 var filter = Builders<IVideo>.Filter.Eq("_id", doc.Id);
 await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter , doc, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB drivers 2.4.4, using "Equal" comparison on a filter (without knowing about "_id"):

```
var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Id, doc.Id);
await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, doc, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```